# How to load custom minted lexer from file with czech babel

Tags: babel, minted

I would like to distribute my own lexer with latex sources.
I use:

```
\begin{minted}{myLexer.py:MyLexerClassName -x}
setMinAndMax
\end{minted}
```

which works fine.
But when I use czech babel, compilation fails with error: **"The control sequence marked < to be read again > should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname."**

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{myLexer.py:MyLexerClassName -x}
setMinAndMax
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

When it works (one of the choices):

1. If I use system lexer
2. If I don't use babel package
3. If I use other language (I tried magyar)

Ultimately I would like to use this in beamer environment, but beamer is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Just a guess: maybe it could help to switch off some czech specific `\shorthandoff`, but I don't know which shortshands are used in czech, neither can I test without your lexer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks samcarter for suggestion.
Changing this:

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
```

to this:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,czech]{babel}
```

solved the problem.